# Como obtener los TextBlock de una imagen usando TextRecognizer de forma verticalmente

Tags: java, android, ocr

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación para Android que lee texto de una imagen para poder escanear un DNI. Para esto uso el objeto `TextRecognizer` y su método `.detect(Frame)` al cuál se le pasa un `frame` y él lo analiza retornando un objeto `SparseArray<TextBlock>` el cuál se puede iterar para así obtener todo el texto que se ha sacado de la imagen. Hasta ahí todo bien. El problema viene a la hora de interpretar el texto debido a que me vienen palabras desordenadas y no sé cómo decidir qué es el apellido, qué es el nombre etc. Lo normal sería que, en el DNI (Español) el primer apellido fuera lo que está debajo del label Primer apellido, la cosa es que no sé cómo obtener lo que leo de una forma ordenada y vertical para así saber por orden que es cada cosa. Es raro de explicar pero aquí les dejo una foto de un DNI falso y lo explico mejor:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando yo escaneo esta imagen y recorro el `Array` que me ha llegado, a lo mejor me llega la palabra "primer" como me llega la palabra "Carmen" primero, y después la siguiente iteración me llega el "IDESP"...

Lo que necesito es saber si hay una posibilidad de escanear la imagen verticalmente y que lo primero que me llegue sea "DOCUMENTO NACIONAL DE IDENTIDAD", lo segundo "PRIMER APELLIDO", después el dicho apellido y así sucesivamente.

Comment: No estás solo, pero tampoco recibió respuesta: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45618476/579895

Comment: Siempre puedes dividir la imagen por áreas y pasar el reconocimiento a cada área de forma individual. Requiere más trabajo pero divides el texto en unidades elementales. Piensa que es un formato estándar y si eres capaz de detectar los límites del DNI debería ser sencillo trocear la imagen para obtener lo que necesitas (Nombre, Apellidos, ...)

Comment: Razón no te falta, pero no tengo ni idea de cómo trocearía la imagen, de hecho soy nuevo en esto de escanear imágenes :/

Comment: Esta pregunta esta muy interesante, leere algo a ver si puedo ser de ayuda.

Comment: Gracias! Yo todavía sigo sin saber cómo hacerlo